# How to get Rpi 3 to current mode in script

Tags: pi-3

I have a script that runs on RPi which is triggered from mobile to switch RPi to station/master mode. It works properly. 
Now my issue is I want to know the current mode of RPi (Ad-hoc/master) in shell script. Which I will broadcast via MDNS.

There is iwconfig but its response chnages so I am not sure how to read Mode programatically.

Can some one help me.

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```bash
iwconfig wlan0 | grep Mode | cut -d ':' -f 2 | awk '{print $1}'
```